# Is it possible to make the following noun phrase possessive? a girl in pink's name?

Tags: possessives

Is it possible to make the following noun phrase possessive?
a girl in pink's name (or a girl's in pink name? or a girl's name wearing pink?)

Comment: the noun phrase ***a girl in pink's name*** is syntactically valid, but it's awkward, and would rarely if ever be used by a native speaker. It's a very unusual *meaning* anyway (especially with the *indefinite* article ***a** girl*), but if we needed to refer to it at all, we'd call it ***the name of a girl in pink***. Your other two suggestions are both syntactically invalid anyway, so just forget all three of them.

Comment: Yes. The boy in blue's father, the man in black's body, the Lady in Green's poem.

Comment: The _name_ is neither pink nor wearing pink, so the last two make no sense.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: But it's not so easy to cite examples with ***a** girl in pink's..., **a** boy in blue's..., **a** Lady in Green's...* ! :)

Comment: Why is it difficult to cite such examples? The sentence 'Do you know that girl in pink's name?" sounds quite natural to me.

Comment: @Natalia - I found _I want a gif of that girl in pink's face_, and also _the shooting probably saved that girl in pink's life_.

Comment: [**The girl in pink**] *is called Angel* OR *The name of that **girl** [dressed] **in pink** is Angel*" I think you would find that is how the majority of speakers would use that type of noun phrase.

Comment: @Natalia: There's a huge difference between ***a** girl* (any unspecified girl) and ***that** girl* (referencing ***one specific girl*** known within the current context). Or ***the** girl*, which is equally specific.

Comment: Does the article/demonstrative change the possessive structure?

Answer (score 2):

This is syntactically fine but not very nice.

> Your challenge is to learn a girl in pink's name.

> Your challenge is to learn the name of a girl in pink.

Both mean go and find a girl wearing pink and find out her name, but the second is easier to parse. The first version sounds almost cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

Not a native speaker, but anyway I feel that "**the** girl in pink's name" would be more acceptable (if it has been referred to before) because it there is a stronger indication that "the girl in pink" is the phrase in the possessive.

In "**a** girl in pink's name" the cohesion (is it cohesion?) seems weaker, so my first thought when I read the question was that "in pink's name" had to be some extravagant jocularly idiomatic variety of "in God's name". At least that was my spontaneous reaction.